# What is jQuery.Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vtiger

I'm wondering what the following code is doing:

```
jQuery.Class("Vtiger_Helper_Js",{ });
```

I'm asking because I can't figure out what `jQuery.Class` is about...

Comment: Could be http://bitovi.com/blog/2010/06/a-simple-powerful-lightweight-class-for-jquery.html, who knows. It's not a standard jQuery method.

Comment: Where did you find said code?

Comment: I found it in vtiger/resourcs/helper.js

Comment: It is a method that someone or something has defined on `jQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vtiger CRM uses the [jQuery.Class plugin, available here](http://bitovi.com/blog/2010/06/a-simple-powerful-lightweight-class-for-jquery.html).

You can see it in the repository in the [libraries folder](https://github.com/clandmeter/vtiger/blob/v6.0.0/libraries/jquery/jquery.class.min.js).

Answer (score -2):

This is what is called `jQuery.class.js` which is a plugin to supersede prototype.js basically since jQuery is huge now.

*Several of the methods in this plugin use code adapated from Prototype*

Meaning they basically made jQuery and prototype.js one language to easily transition those who use prototype.js to jQuery or at least help thme

Comment: `jQuery.Class(...)`   `.Class()` is the Plugin and `Vtiger_Helper_Js` is the method within the plugin